Why was a character rescued from the lift shaft?
Towards the end of Alien: Romulus, the character

Rain falls down the lift shaft when the gravity is re-enabled. She is 'rescued' by a xenomorph that was climbing up the shaft. It grabs her with its tail, sets her back on the ladder and then moves in for a close-up of her, 'Alien3' style.

However, unlike Alien3, she was not (as far as we know) carrying a parasite. We've not seen any situations she could've been infected/implanted. The Alien had no reason to rescue her. It would either a) kill her as a threat, or b) capture her to use as an incubator.
Is it meant to imply that she has been infected and we just didn't notice it? Or is it just an excuse to do yet more fan-service and copy a scene from one of the earlier movies? Or is there some other reason for it?

As said in the other answer, a live host is required for the facehugger.
You may have missed it, but the characters face also has confusion about why she has been saved, only for her to have her attention taken by something other than the xenomorph and so she glances to her left:
The shot changes to show a facehugger creeping around the corner towards her, ready to pounce.

 Conveniently, Andy has seen all this, and is hurtling down with his gun (retrieved a  moment ago) shooting both of the bad guys (facehugger mid-flight) and ending with a horrible line that didn't need to be taken from another film that happens 37 years later...

So, in summary, the xenomorph saved her so she can be impregnated by the facehugger waiting around the corner.

This is a link to the scene I found on the internet - due to its 'source' it could be taken down at any time.



If that happens the screencaps are:


Ah, I completely missed the facehugger's appearance! But yes, that would explain it.

It is very quick, and all the official clips released that have this scene, interestingly edit out the presence of the facehugger...

Facehuggers need a live host to attach themselves to, and likely as healthy a host as possible.

(As evidenced by the nest not implanting Kay despite hauling her live body to the nest, due to her injuries)

While not directly explained, its possible that the xenomorph that caught Rain wanted to bring her back to its nest so she could be implanted with a facehugger to further spread the nest. She had dropped her weapon at this point, and likely wasn't perceived as a threat to it.

The problem with this suggestion is that the alien released her and gently placed her safely on the latter. If it wanted to capture her then it'd have held on to her and taken her away, surely?

It likely would have done the same if it wanted her dead, too. They certainly don't need their tails to kill captured prey.
